# vectorised matching of values with numerical tolerance

Tags: r, match, precision

I'm trying to match values in a numeric vector to a discrete set of values, but due to rounding errors they're not necessarily an exact match. Consider the following example, converting spherical coordinates to cartesian, and trying to match the resulting distance against the original r values,

```
phithetar <- expand.grid(theta=seq(0,pi,length=10),
                        phi = seq(0, 2*pi, length=10),
                        r = seq(1,10))

xyz <- transform(phithetar, x = r*sin(theta)*cos(phi),
                                 y = r*sin(theta)*sin(phi),
                                 z = r*cos(theta))

xyz <- transform(xyz,  newr = sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2))

with(xyz, sum(newr != r))
```

This is non-zero, as the operations have results in lost precision.

Here's my slow implementation to match values within a given tolerance; the iteration over x makes it slow. An alternative would be to expand all (x,y) combinations but that'd be memory-heavy for large vectors.

```
match_closest <- function(x, y, tol=1e-5){

  match_one <- function(.x) {
    difs <- abs(.x - y)
    best <- which.min(difs)
    if(difs[best] > tol) message(.x, " ain't so close to ", y[best])
    y[best]
  }
  vapply(x, match_one, 0)

}

rvalues <- unique(phithetar$r)
xyz <- transform(xyz,  matchedr = match_closest(newr, rvalues))

with(xyz, sum(matchedr != r))
```

I tried another idea with `cut()`,

```
match_closenough <- function(x, y, tol=1e-5){

  levs <- c(y-0.5*tol, y+0.5*tol)
  f <- cut(x, breaks=levs, include.lowest = TRUE)
  y[f]

}
```

but it doesn't quite work. Similarly, this rounding trick

```
match_closenough <- function(x, y, tol=1e-3){

  dig <- -log10(tol)
  y[match(round(x, dig), round(y, dig), nomatch = NA)]

}
```

kind of works and is faster, but feels too fragile.

Comment: Could you post two sample vectors you are trying to compare and what kind of output you expect?

Comment: I gave an example at the start – the goal is to match `xyz$newr` to `1:10` (`unique(phithetar$r))`)

Comment: I still do not understand how the result shall look like. Every function returns a different result.

Comment: the first function works as desired, it's just really slow. The desired output is to recover `r` from `sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)` without the imprecision of the round-trip

Answer (score 1):

I think the `cut()` version can be made to work with a few amendments (though factors always seem outside my control),

```
match_madethecut <- function(x, y, tol=1e-5){

  breaks <- sort(c(y-0.5*tol, y+0.5*tol))
  f <- cut(x, breaks=breaks, include.lowest = TRUE)
  rep(sort(y),each=2)[as.numeric(f)]

}
```

Note that `y` is expected to contain unique values, in practice. This seems fast, as expected since `cut()` does the comparisons at C level.

Comment: You can solve the restriction for unique y values by simply inserting ```y<-unique(y)``` as the first line of the function.

Comment: This is a very nice, concise, solution, which runs at a comparable speed to the *much more complicated* ```sloppy_match``` solution that I proposed.

Comment: Note that it won't generally choose the *closest* among ```y``` values within the ```tol``` range if there are more-than-one (try ```x=c(1.04,1.05,1.06,1.95); y=c(1,1.03,1.05,1.08,2); match_madethecut(x,y,tol=0.2)```, but this mightn't be a problem (especially if ```tol``` is used to represent the maximum useful level of precision).

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is just to match values within some (very-)small tolerance to account for loss-of-precision during sequential floating-point operations (as in the example), then I think that your last `match_closenough()` solution is elegant and fast, and doesn't look particularly 'fragile' to me.

The only possible limitation with this approach in general seems that you're restricted to rounding by powers-of-10 (rather than arbitrarily-chosen `tol` values), and that you can't easily use `tol` values greater than 1.  Both of these cases don't really apply your example, of course, but there might be situations where they might become relevant.

So: what if we *insist* on choosing arbitrary `tol` values, and want a *vectorized* function?  One solution would be to write it in RCpp (and this would probably not be any longer than the R-only solution...).

But this *can* be done 'from scratch' in R: this solution uses several steps in order to avoid ever requiring a non-vectorized function:

```
# define sloppy_match:
sloppy_match=function(x,y,tol=.Machine$double.eps,nomatch=NA) {
    # combine x & y indices:
        v=c(x,y)
        i=c(rep(1,length(x)),rep(0,length(y)))[order(v)]
        xi=cumsum(i==1)
        yi=cumsum(i==0)
    # find y values above and below each x value
        xrank=rank(x,ties="first")
        yi_below=yi[match(xrank,xi,NA)]
        yi_above=yi_below+1
        yi_below[yi_below==0]=NA
        yi_above[yi_above>length(y)]=NA
        ysort=sort(y)   
        y_below=ysort[yi_below]
        y_above=ysort[yi_above]
    # now choose closest y value to each x:
        closest_y=y_below
        to_change=is.na(y_below)|(x-closest_y>y_above-x)&!is.na(y_above)
        closest_y[to_change]=y_above[to_change]
    # and reject any that aren't close enough
        closest_y[abs(x-closest_y)>tol]=nomatch
    return(closest_y)
}
```

Try it out:

```
vec1=sample(1:10,5000,replace=T)+rnorm(50)*1e-6
vec2=sample(1:10,5000,replace=T)

test=sloppy_match(vec1,vec2,tol=1e-3)
all(abs(test-vec1)<1e-3)
# TRUE
```

How does this compare in terms of speed?

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(match(vec1,vec1),
    match_closest(vec1,vec2,tol=1e-5),
    match_closenough(vec1,vec2,tol=1e-5),
    sloppy_match(vec1,vec2,tol=1e-5),
    times=10)
# Unit: microseconds
#                                       expr        min         lq        mean      median         uq        max neval
#                          match(vec1, vec1)    190.672    191.683    217.7785    199.9135    219.783    357.662    10
#     match_closest(vec1, vec2, tol = 1e-05) 186051.018 205712.022 208032.1262 209191.3980 215335.356 221682.351    10
#  match_closenough(vec1, vec2, tol = 1e-05)    511.426    513.772    531.2815    530.7850    544.416    561.935    10
#      sloppy_match(vec1, vec2, tol = 1e-05)   4110.814   4279.376   5859.7425   4301.0610   4608.116  18587.816    10
```

So the built-in `match()` is obviously fastest when the values are exactly-equal, and for close-enough matching if rounding to less-than-one powers-of-ten is acceptable (and I bet that this will be the case in 99% of circumstances), the `match_closenough()` is fastest.

Finally, the `sloppy_match()` approach to allow matching to arbitrarily-chosen tolerances is somewhat slower than these, but the benefit of vectorization is obvious: it's already almost 40x faster than the non-vectorized `match_closest()` approach, with only 5000 elements, and this difference becomes even-more pronounced when the number of elements increases.

So, in the end, you'll probably want to choose between the two approaches depending on the particular tolerance requirement; but both of them will be hundreds of times faster than the non-vectorized approach for large vectors.

Comment: nice detailed answer, thanks! At first glance your solution looks a bit like the idea of using `cut()` which I still think should be able to work (and should be quite fast, and concise). I should try to pin down what went wrong with it on a small example.

Comment: I think the problem with ```cut``` is that it isn't really vectorized to take multiple parallel '```breaks```' vectors, so it'll probably need a loop (or apply) somewhere.

Comment: A frequent bugbear of trying to create fast, vectorized code in R is that it's sometimes rather convoluted to avoid non-vectorized solutions, which are often much prettier and more-concise (but *much* slower)!

Comment: ...but if you do manage to somehow find a slicker vectorized way to solve this, please do share it (and accept your own answer if it's better than my clunky one or anyone else's!).

Comment: not sure if any one solution is universally better but I'm happy to report that using `cut()` seems to be a decent possibility.

Comment: I love it!  +1 vote from me!  There's a slight issue when the ```y``` values are very close (see my comment)...